# Windows Server 2012 R2 Unable to Access File Share

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a newly installed Server 2012 R2, Physical Host. Joined to the Domain. When I try to access a file share on a different (older, not sure how old but it might be 2008 R2) DFS File share I get the following error message

> `Network Error`
>
> `Windows Cannot Access "file Share Location"`
>
> `Error Code: 0x80070035`
>
> `The Network path was not found`

This is only happening from the 2012 R2 server. From 2008 R2 Server I can access the share. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Define "older". So old it is not compatible anymore with 2012, which iirdc would bea security change done around 2003 timeframe, i.e. ancient and something every admin would have changed years ago?

Comment: Can you provide more details in your post?  Like can you ping the DFS namespace by name?  Can you access a share setup on the 2012 R2 server?  Can you view the shares if you just go to \\DFSroot from the 2012 server?  Can you ping the DFS server by hostname from the 2012 server?